# PSR7 on Laravel Routes: access to latest params

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, psr-7

Hi have the next route

```
Route::get('/{param1}',
        'Http\Controllers\SomeController@getCollection');
Route::get('/{param_for_middleware}/{param1}',
        'Http\Controllers\SomeController@getCollection');
```

And, on my controller, I have

```
// PSR7 code
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class SomeController extends Controller
    public function getCollection(ServerRequestInterface $request)
    {
        // here, I need access to param1
        dd($request);
    }
}
```

With Original Laravel Router We can get value with `$this->route()->parameters()['param1]`. But, when we use PSR7 on Laravel?

Comment: why don't you use $request->get('param1') ??? as usual..

Comment: Because `get()` is not defined on `Zend\\Diactoros\\ServerRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, still using the good old method?

```
public function getCollection(ServerRequestInterface $request, $param1)
{
    // here is your param1!
    dd($param1);
}
```

**Edit**

If you need more than one parameters and you need to ensure their positions, you could do this:

```
public function getCollection(
    ServerRequestInterface $request,
    \Illuminate\Http\Request $illuminateRequest
)
{
    // here is your param1 & param_for_middleware!
    dd($illuminateRequest->route('param1') . ' & ' .
       $illuminateRequest->route('param_for_middleware'));
}
```

Comment: Don't work on `Route::get('/{param_for_middleware}/{param1}',      'Http\Controllers\SomeController@getCollection');` because dump `{param_for_middleware}`, not `{param1}`

Comment: Yep provided an alternative @pablorsk